# Using between in the SQL IN clause

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, between

Is there any way possible to use a range in the IN clause of sql.

I have a scenario where I have the values in the column like:

```
BIN_1_1
111111 - 222222
```

The user enters a value, eg; 111134, and I need to check if the value entered lies within the range in the column value.

Is there any way to use IN statement and use between in it ?

```
  FOR i in (select * from V_CUS_SEG_BIN_RANGE) LOOP    
    IF v_input1 IN 
      (REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.bin_1_1, '[^-]+', 1, 1), REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.bin_1_1, '[^-]+', 1, 2)
    THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Duplicate!');
END LOOP;
```

I get the values separated with RegEx, but can I use between to compare if the values lies in between the range.

Comment: No, that is not how `in` works.  Just use `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: how exactly do I embed >= and <= ?

Comment: This would be much easier if `111111` and `222222` were in separate columns of `INT`.  As it is, anything could be in a column that allows the value `111111 - 222222`, which makes many methods of solving this very fragile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the results of your REGEXP_SUBSTR calls in a BETWEEN condition, as in:

```
IF v_input1 BETWEEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.bin_1_1, '[^-]+', 1, 1)
                AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.bin_1_1, '[^-]+', 1, 2) OR
   v_input1 BETWEEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.bin_1_2, '[^-]+', 1, 1)
                AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.bin_1_2, '[^-]+', 1, 2) OR
   v_input1 BETWEEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.bin_1_3, '[^-]+', 1, 1)
                AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(i.bin_1_3, '[^-]+', 1, 2)
THEN
   ...whatever...
END IF;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I have multiple of bin columns - bin_1_2, bin_1_3 so on. 
do I separate it with OR ?